# Unable to create ~/.ssh file using .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, cicd

The following code was from my deploy stage in my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
deploy_website:
  stage: deploy
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  before_script:
    - "command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh )"
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - pwd && ls
    - ssh-keyscan $VM_IPADDRESS >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    # - apk add bash
    # - ls deploy
    # - bash ./deploy/deploy.sh
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$VM_IPADDRESS "hostname && echo 'Welcome!!!' > welcome.txt"
```

This line "ssh-keyscan $VM_IPADDRESS >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts" failed to run when I execute my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can start and `echo $VM_IPADDRESS` to check if the IP variable is properly instanciated.

> "failed to run"

Then it depends on the error message (or if the commands simply froze).
Before the keyscan, you can test if the network route is reachable from your GitLab-CI runnner with:

```
curl -v telnet://$VM_IPADDRESS:22
```

If it does not connect immediately, that would explain why the `ssh-keyscan` fails.